# function is overriding variable declared in other scope

Tags: javascript

I have to functions both using i as an iterator.
One function is using the other.
I thought local Variables cant be changed by other scopes.
But now "i" is changed after the "createOptions" function.
Is it possible that the value is passed by the object?

```
    function createOptions(array) {
       var optionArray = [];
       for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
         var option = $("<option></option").text(array[i]);
         $(option).attr("value", array[i]);
         optionArray.push(option);
       } 
       return optionArray;
     }

     function buildForm(players) {
       var form = $("<form></form>");
       for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
         var playernumber = "player " + (i+1).toString();
         var select = $("<select></select>").attr({
          "id" : playernumber,
          "onchange" : "addNewPlayer(this)"
         });
         var selectPlayerOption = $("<option></option>").text("-- select Player --");
         $(selectPlayerOption).attr({
           "disabled" : true,
           "selected" : true
         })
         var newPlayerOption = $("<option></option>").text("New Player");
         var playerOptions = createOptions(players);
         console.log(playerOptions.j);
         $(select).append(selectPlayerOption, newPlayerOption, playerOptions);
         $(form).append(select); 
       }
       $("#maincontent").append(form);
     }
```

Comment: declare it as scoped variable instead of global... `(let i = 0; ...` when you don't declare a variable with `var`, `let` or `const`, it becomes global, you can even access it by window.variableName which is probably something you don't want

Comment: Are you sure you have defined the variable `i` somewhere? Where is its `var` keyword to define it? :P

Comment: "*local Variables cant be changed by other scopes.*' That's indeed true but `i` is not a local variable - it's global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the variable like `i = 0` even if it is inside a `for` loop still will be created as global variable.

Suggested way instead:

```
for (let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
   // your code
}
```

Read further [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) about `let`.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

that is normal your function buildForm is using i as an iterator and when CreateOption is called inside buildForm function it value is reassigned to 0 because of this line `for (i=0;i<array.length;i++)` in createOption function.
So unless you want to use i in both functions i suggest to use two differents iterators i and j for example

Comment: Why not simply declare them local, so they don't clash? Using shared globals doesn't scale at all.

Comment: yes it is a possibility but not a best practice if we consider that he is using an ECMAScript version that does not support declaring a variable locally whit the 'let' statement

Comment: `var` will declare the variable to be local. Local to a function but still won't clash with another local-to-a-function variable. You only need `let`/`const` to make a variable block-level.